# UnityHub "Not Enough Space" error on Linux

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have 40 gb of free space and unityhub says only 8.8 gb is required to install editor.
But I get "not enough space" error.[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpch0.png) [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inW0D.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you try to install Unity on Linux and you get not enough space error have in mind that Unity Hub downloads the files in your /tmp/ folder first. If your home directory is on another partition while root (or /tmp ) on a smaller one, that causes the issue.

**Solution**

Set another TEMP directory before running the AppImage. If you use bash, that would be:

```
TEMP=~/tmp ./UnityHub.AppImage
```

Assumptions:

You are in the same folder with AppImage.

You have created the tmp folder in your home directory `(mkdir ~/tmp)`.

Answer (score 2):

I met this question in 2021, the answer is still correct, the /tmp directory is too small. But now there is an easier solution, because there is now a setting in Unity Hub called Download Location under Installs.

Answer (score 0):

Go into developer settings and then in the linux developer environment increase the disk size to allow for more disk space on that user.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer**
as temp does not allow to have use of too much space just do this.

```
mkdir ~/tempfornow
```

and if you have installed from aur then

```
TEMP=~/tempfornow unityhub
```

or if you have installed from appImage then

```
TEMP=~/tempfornow /location/of/appimage/appimagename.AppImage
```

Done

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the only thing I did was from the Hub settings to change the path of the installations folder to /home/your username. You have to change both installs location and downloads location